# is there any node.js module to deploy actions on google using actions sdk instead of gactions CLI command?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

Usually to create or update actions on google  project using actions sdk we user gactions.exe file and will run the below command

```
gactions update --action_package action.json --project <project_id>
```

is there any node.js module to do this instead of gactions CLI command?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: There isn't, but if there's a specific use-case you're looking for you may be able to work around it.

Comment: Possibly you can call the executable from Node.js using their [childProcess](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) api.